# Need help understanding basic pseudocode algorithm problems

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, pseudocode

May I trouble anyone to help me understand how this sort of pseudocode algorithm works and how it arrived at the correct answer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are questions with traps in them. It is testing whether you really look closely to every aspect of the code for both question 6 and question 7:

### Question 6

The first code can be expressed in JavaScript as follows:

```js
function Find2(s, n) {
    let EleFound = s[0]
    for (let i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (s[i] > EleFound) {
            EleFound = i
        }
    }
    return EleFound
}

let result = Find2([3, 15, 7, 9], 4);
console.log(result);
```

When you run it, you'll see it outputs 0. Once you see it, it is obvious, but the line `EleFound = i` is assigning the *index*, not `s[i]`! And as the index `i` is decreasing to zero, ***and*** `s[1]` is greater than the initial value of `EleFound`, `EleFound` will get the value 1, not 15! And in the last iteration it will get assigned 0, because `s[0]` is greater than 1(!).

### Question 7

The second code can be run as:

```js
function AddMul5(A, n) {
    let sum = A[0]
    for (let i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
        sum = sum + i
    }
    return sum
}

let result = AddMul5([3, 5, 7, 9], 5);
console.log(result);
```

The output is 13. Did you spot the trap here? It is quite similar...

Hints:

> which values from `A` are used in this sum?

> Is `A[1]` used at all?